# making a certain set of floated elements responsive on resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have floated some elements side by side, what I would like to do is somehow make the `.line` elements shrink in width of the user resizes the screen so in some ways make only those elements responsive. I was thinking that i could give `.line` a % width or some kind of overflow so that when the page sizes down the width either reduces or gets hidden by the overflow but these don't seem to work. Can anyone recommend another option or how I could make my idea work? I know I could use media queries to alter the widths etc but I would like this to be natural to allow for different text sizes/lengths etc

Here is the code http://dabblet.com/gist/4753624

CSS

```
.l {
    float: left;
}
span {
    display: block;
}
.line {
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
}
.icon {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/40/000/fff') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="holder clearfix">
    <div class="headline clearfix"> 
        <span class="l icon ir"></span>
        <span class="l line"></span>

         <h1 class="l">Main HEadline</h1>
        <span class="l line"></span>
        <span class="l icon ir"></span>

    </div>

    <div class="headline clearfix"> 
        <span class="l icon ir"></span>
        <span class="l line"></span>

         <h1 class="l">Main HEadline</h1>
        <span class="l line"></span>
        <span class="l icon ir"></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries are what you want:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .line {
            // your css rules 
        }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, i was hoping I could do this without using media queries so they naturally reduce or increase in size?

Comment: I'm really not sure how else you could get this to reliably work without using media queries. You could use JavaScript but that would probably incure a larger overhead than using plain css.